# Jsoup post method in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, jsoup

I want to enter data into a website using Android studio using jsoup 
And the website URL does not change even after going to next page
So how could I do that.

Answer (score 0):

That  is not possible by Jsoup,you may need to java  selenium  to accomplish your task

Comment: Can you give selenium Gradle dependencies for Android studio

Comment: No idea am sorry